# Lots (all?) of my JavaScript code breaks in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I am unable to use a lot of JavaScript functionality in Internet Explorer 9 on Stack Overflow. The dropdown menu that appears when I float over my name, the Stack Exchange history dropdown, the hyperlink insertion and other menu items in creating new questions, voting, adding comments, etc. all fails. It seems most anything that I expect to be JavaScript fails.

In looking at [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug) I see:

**Error**

> SCRIPT1015: Unterminated string constant  full.js?v=a56a3c2dc16e, line
>   63 character 148

If I use Firefox, things work fine. If I go to Meta-Stack or Programmers stack in Internet Explorer 9 things also work fine. I am only experiencing the issue on Stack Overflow. It started today. It was working fine on Friday.

Comment: Hmmm... there could be a cache issue. This seems so 1990's, but have you cleared your cache, lately?

Comment: @AndrewBarber - That corrected the issue.  Thank you.  What causes that to occur?  Is it code I downloaded from the site that just so happened to be in a broken state or the file was modified on my machine somehow or other?

Comment: Probably a change in the site's code somewhere; your browser had the old stuff cached.

Comment: It would be so nice to be able to clear cache and other such related items to just one site rather than having to do sweeping deletes for the whole browser...

Comment: That would be a nice feature, especially on a browser that it seems *still* ignores the proper behavior of "Refresh" sometimes.

Comment: I just tripped over the same problem.  Deleting the "browse history" fixed the problem, if that's you mean by "clearing the cache".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the code linked in different places on the site changes, sometimes your browser will still use the old version. Normally, a hard refresh (F5 on windows, eg) will update all of that, but sometimes that does not work. Anecdotally, this seems to happen in IE more than other browsers.

The solution in such a case is to clear the browser's cache, forcing it to pull down the recent versions of all files involved.